# Cannot run jsdoc via Gulp on Windows 7 with child_process

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, gulp, jsdoc

My builds were running fine with gulp and numerous plugins.  When attempting to run them again recently on an older project, I received a warning that gulp-run has been deprecated.  We have recently upgraded Node to 5.0.0.

When we run our documentation tasks for jsdoc the gulp-run process was used, and the node_modules\.bin\jsdoc was called, which in turn calls the jsdoc.js script as jsdoc installs everything

In trying to remove the deprecated gulp-run(), and switch to the recommended child_process, errors are generated by the child_process.exec since there is not an executable or batch file, but instead, the jsdoc runs a .js (JavaScript file) on the native Windows OS, when calling cmd /c.

The system is now returning `'node_modules\.bin\jsdoc' is not recognized as an internal or external command` using the gulp-run().

Switching to try to use the child_process.spawn:

```
gulp.task('docs', function () {
    var shell = require('child_process').spawn;
    var child = shell('node_modules/.bin/jsdoc', [
                SourceCode,
                '-c', 'jsdoc.json',
                '-t', 'node_modules/angular-jsdoc/default',
                '-d', DocumentationPath,
                './README.md',
                '-r', 'app/'
            ],
            { stdio: 'inherit' });

//  child.stdout.on('data', function(data) { console.log('stdout: ' + data); } );
//  child.stderr.on('data', function(data) { console.log('stdout: ' + data); } );
    child.on('exit', function(code)    { console.log('exit: ' + code); } );
});
```

Returns an error:

```
events.js:141
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: spawn node_modules/.bin/jsdoc ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:860:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
    at doNTCallback2 (node.js:450:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:364:17)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:459:11)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:972:3
```

Using the child_process.exec:

```
gulp.task('docs', function () {
    var shell = require('child_process').exec;
    var child = shell('node_modules/.bin/jsdoc', [
                RootDir.home + SourcePath.SourceCode,
                '-c', RootDir.config + 'jsdoc.json',
                '-t', 'node_modules/angular-jsdoc/default',
                '-d', RootDir.docs + DocumentationPath.API,
                './README.md',
                '-r', RootDir.home + Paths.Modules
            ],
            { stdio: 'inherit' });

    child.stdout.on('data', function(data) { console.log('stdout: ' + data); } );
    child.stderr.on('data', function(data) { console.log('stdout: ' + data); } );
    child.on('exit', function(code)    { console.log('exit: ' + code); } );
});
```

Error:

```
stdout: 'node_modules' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

exit: 1
```

Changing the call to use backslashes for Windows:

```
gulp.task('docs', function () {
    var shell = require('child_process').exec;
    var child = shell('node_modules\\.bin\\jsdoc', [
                RootDir.home + SourcePath.SourceCode,
                '-c', RootDir.config + 'jsdoc.json',
                '-t', 'node_modules/angular-jsdoc/default',
                '-d', RootDir.docs + DocumentationPath.API,
                './README.md',
                '-r', RootDir.home + Paths.Modules
            ],
            { stdio: 'inherit' });

    child.stdout.on('data', function(data) { console.log('stdout: ' + data); } );
    child.stderr.on('data', function(data) { console.log('stdout: ' + data); } );
    child.on('exit', function(code)    { console.log('exit: ' + code); } );
});
```

Returns an error:

```
stdout: 'node_modules\.bin\jsdoc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

exit: 1
```

I have also tried calling the JS file:

```
var child = shell('node_modules\\jsdoc\\jsdoc.js', [
...
```

This gives a Windows error from trying to run a JavaScript file on its own.

[image: Line 1/Char 1 - Invalid Character - Microsoft JScript compilation error]

I am at a loss as to how to try to get the JS to run on the newer version of Node.

Comment: Fund the answer? I'm also getting: `'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` when inputing: `./node_modules/.bin/jsdoc src/web/webApp.js`

Comment: Solved my ptoblem, I should have used backslashes: `node_modules\.bin\jsdoc src\web\webApp.js`

Comment: @AdrianMoisa This was working in previous versions though, where I did not need to use the backslash being on Windows, as Gulp seemed to process internally correctly.  I also tried: var child = shell('node_modules\\jsdoc\\jsdoc.js',  which had the backslash, but the shell does not seem to run properly, and I get the Windows error.